# How to draw colormap with 2 values at the same time?

Tags: python, colormap

I wonder how to make this kind of color map:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSIdz.png)

I hope to draw this kind of map. I have two values for each grid already(which is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRrRw.png)(p,et),(R,et)), so I need how to adopt this colormap with my correlation values. But I have no idea how to make this colormap. 
reference : A. J. Teuling.A regional perspective on trends in continental evaporation.
Thanks!

Comment: You can use your own colormap e..g in openCV.  So you'd need to map your 2 values to a single colormap value, which it looks like you could do by varying Hue around the perimeter and decreasing Saturation to as you go approach 0,0, ie. Hue=k*theta and Sat=r^2 , Val=120

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if I possible to make 2d colormap at first, but I think it is impossible for me right now. I'll try what you suggest.

Comment: I was suggesting a way to reproduce the 2D colormap in the figure! The RGB value for your look-up-table is calculated as function of two dimensions on the square shown in your figure. Going around the edges of the square, the hue varies. Going towards middle of square, the saturation varies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it along these lines:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
def get_rgb(two_d_pixels):
    theta = np.arctan(two_d_pixels[1,:] / two_d_pixels[0,:])
    r = np.sqrt(two_d_pixels[1,:]**2 +  two_d_pixels[0,:]**2)
    hue = (theta+3.14/2) * 128./(3.14)  # 127 max for hue
    sat = (r/np.sqrt(2)) * 255 #255 max for sat
    H,W = two_d_pixels.shape[1:3]
    retval = np.zeros([H,W,3],dtype = np.uint8)
    retval[:,:,0] = hue
    retval[:,:,1] = sat
    retval[:, :, 2] = 255
    retval = cv2.cvtColor(retval,cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    return retval

two_d_image = np.mgrid[-1:1:0.1,-1:1:0.1]
rgb = get_rgb(two_d_image)
cv2.imshow('ok',rgb)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This shows the map from ((-1,1),(-1,1)) to RGB, example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kPz0.jpg) .
I used mgrid to make a 2*X*Y tensor , the rho_p and rho_rg are the values in those two tensor planes. If you need the colormap exactly like in the paper you can adjust the formulas for hue,sat , keeping in mind that arctan ranges from -pi/2 to pi/2 and r will range from sqrt(2) to 0

Comment: if you think the answer suffices, i encourage you to click the check mark indicating its an accepted answer.

Comment: Ok! Your method was so nice, but I did it with matlab successfully. I made 90*90*3 matrix filled with rgb numbers and fitted it with my data. Anyway, your recommendation helped me a lot.